# Как вывести сообщение в функции и начать функцию с начала Python

Tags: python

Нужно вывести сообщение об ошибке и начать функцию с начала, если пользователь вводит не число, а буквы или иные символы. Можно ли это сделать с типом данных Float?

```
def inpt ():
    while True:
        a = input('Введите целое положительное число: ')
        if a.isdigit():
            return a
        else:
            print('Ошибка')
a = inpt()
print(a)d
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно (с обработкой исключений):

```
def inpt ():
    while True:
        a = input('Введите целое положительное число: ')
        try:
            a=float(a)
            return a
        except ValueError: print('Ошибка')
a = inpt()
print(a)
```

Или с `replace()`:

```
def inpt ():
    while True:
        a = input('Введите целое положительное число: ')
        if a.isdigit or a.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit(): return a
        else: print('Ошибка')
print(inpt())
```

Comment: В том и дело, что нужно без обработки, а в ручную :(

Comment: @SemyonPankratov изменил, теперь как?

Comment: `if a.isdigit` вы забыли вызвать метод

Comment: Работает, но как сделать это с дробными числами?

Comment: @Стас исправил уже давно)

Comment: @SemyonPankratov это и есть с дробными. 2 способ

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой способ проверки можно использовать без while True, и проверок на исключения.

```
all = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', '.']

def inpt ():
    x = input('Число: ')
    for i in range(len(x)): # идем циклом по строке
        if x[i] not in all: # тут если есть значение которое не входит в список, то ведет к сообщению об ошибке
            print('Ошибка: некорректное значение')
            return '0'
    return x # если все впорядке, то возвращает число

def While(): # здесь идет условие: пока мы не введем корректное знаенчие, нас будет возвращать к ошибке
    a = '0'
    while a == '0':
        a = inpt()
    return float(a) # перевод и возврат строки

a = While()
print(a)
```